# What is the character encoding of f_mntonname in the statfs struct returned by getmntinfo on OSX?

Tags: java, c, macos, character-encoding, jna

I'm calling getmntinfo using Jna from Java on OS X (Mountain Lion & Mavericks). The returned structure contains the data I want, but currently I'm using the default encoding which Java picks. I don't feel comfortable with this and want to be explicit about the encoding.

getmntinfo : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/getmntinfo.3.html

What is the encoding and where can I find the information?

Comment: OSX filesystem typically uses utf-8 for filenames.  You might try explicitly decoding with that (rather than `file.encoding`, which is the default and is typically `MacRoman` on OSX).